# An artificially sweetened drink

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, lexicon

I have to differentiate drinks with sugar and drinks with non-nutritive sweeteners.

It seems to me that a [sweetened drink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweetened_beverage) can refer to both, and that sweet drinks only contain sugar.

Is there any specific term for drinks with artificial sweeteners ?

Sentence example :

> Drinks with `non-nutritive sweeteners` may be quite as bad for your
>   health as `sweet drinks`.

NB : in French we have to word `édulcorant`, which means "which can give a sweet taste"

**EDIT** : the aim of my question is a scientific article. Thus I want to be as specific as I can.

Comment: They're called _diet drinks_.

Comment: @KarlG Were your comment posted as an answer I'd upvote it.

Comment: @DarrenRinger They did. https://english.stackexchange.com/a/431852/98840

Comment: "sweet drinks" are drinks that taste sweet - whether or not they contain sugar.

Comment: The terminology here is intentionally obfuscated by the sweetener/soft drink industry (aided and abetted by the nutty end of the health food military/industrial complex).

Comment: I'd suggest you pick a term (or three) from [here](http://www2.highlands.edu/academics/divisions/scipe/biology/faculty/harnden/2190/notes/5.htm).

Answer (score 19):

We don't have a single-word term that I'm aware of. We might talk about "drinks with artificial sweeteners" for example. Or a drink might have an advert/label that says "no artificial sweeteners!".

You're correct that "sweetened" may be with sugar or may be artificial. We do have another adjective "sugary" which according to [dicitonary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sugary?s=t) means "sweet" or "excessively sweet", but I would only use it for things which contain actual sugar.

As to your sentence example, I'd probably use:

> Drinks with *artificial sweeteners* may be just as bad for your health as *sugary drinks*.

Comment: The problem with this is that some sweeteners are not artificial, e.g. stevia.

Comment: @Richard - Very true. As of now I have no idea how to work that into my answer (my brain's obviously not in gear).

Comment: Why is that a problem? The OP wants a (different) specific term for artificial sweeteners, there isn't one, so use "artificial sweeteners". Makes sense to me. Whether or not it rules out stevia is moot, surely?  And +1 for "sugary" I think that's the most useful word anyone's introduced to the answers.

Comment: I've seen the term "zero-calorie sweetener" or "low calorie sweetener" used in these contexts.

Answer (score 14):

In English such beverages are called [*diet drinks*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diet_drink) or *sugar-free*. As common as these names may be, their origins lie in advertising and the manufacturers who pay for it.

Until the recent emergence of a natural product, [stevia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stevia), as a sweetener, *artificially sweetened* was accurate, since sweeteners such as aspartame, saccharine, or cyclamates are manufactured chemicals.

In the 1970's the number of beverages sweetened with [high fructose corn syrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-fructose_corn_syrup) skyrocketed. In the advertising sense, then, a *sugar-free* beverage is one free of sucrose, fructose, or glucose.

I am unaware of a categorical term exclusive to these three sugars that would readily eliminate others such as maltose and lactose. So if *sugar-free* is not precise enough, your only option is first to use a longer expression, abbreviate it at its first mention, then use the abbreviation thereafter.

> a beverage sweetened without sucrose, fructose, or glucose (non-SFG beverage)

This type of ad hoc abbreviation is common in academic writing, and if the abbreviation proves useful, others will begin to use it as well.

Comment: The term "diet drinks" is only widespread in the US, and is diminishing even here, at least in marketing.

Comment: Thus the rise of _sugar-free_.

Comment: Diet drink seems a good way to go, but since I'm targeting  scientific reporting, I'm afraid it could be seen as non-scientific. What do you think about it ? Would "sugar-free sweet beverage" sound better ?

Comment: "diet drinks" is widespread in the UK also.

Comment: @DanChaltiel: I've incorporated your concerns in a revision of my answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Not a typo, just the other spelling. See:http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sirup?s=t

Comment: @Mari-LouA. Just did an NGram. Virtually no one uses _sirup_ these days, so I'll switch it out, but unless I'm citing directly, I wouldn't use _theatre, centre,_ or _colour_ either.

Comment: I don't believe "sirup" is standard spelling, maybe it was 100/200 years ago but it's not true today. However, *theatre, centre,* and *colour* are standard British English spellings. I tend to favor the American spelling because I got a bit fed up with (some) users telling me I was misspelling stuff, which is rather different pointing out a typo.

Comment: _sirup_ has its own entry at dictionary.com with no indication that it is no longer a standard or acceptable alternate spelling. The site does conveniently append the entry for _syrup_.  M-W notes at its entry that is is "less common." _Advisor_, however, has no separate entry at dictionary.com, but is listed immediately under the bold-faced _Adviser_.  As the examples provided there, there are still plenty of people are still using the _-or_ spelling.

Answer (score 3):

'So, is there any specific term for drinks with artificial sweeteners?' At present time: NO.

'It seems to me that a sweetened drink can refer to both, and that sweet drinks only contain sugar.'  But that is not necessarily the case either. Some naturally sweet fruit drinks are further sweetened by either natural sugars, artificial sweeteners or both.

Lot of FDA food politics in the states re: food labeling of natural sugars, artificial sugars, and combinations! For those that need to absolutely know, check the labels and/or contact the manufacturer.  Here is a nifty table with labeling guide: [FDA artificial sweeteners](https://www.fda.gov/Food/IngredientsPackagingLabeling/FoodAdditivesIngredients/ucm397725.htm)

And then there is this:

> Nutrasweet in Milk–With No Label? Find Out What’s Really Going On  [nutrasweet in milk without labeling](https://wholenewmom.com/reaching-out/milk-aspartame-nutrasweet-fda-petition-label/) This is a proposal by our government to allow a sweetener without labeling for the public good!

Comment: I'd upvote your comment if it wasn't for the "wholenewmom" link.

Answer (score 1):

The word "sweetened" implies that an action has been taken to sweeten the drink.  "Sweet" on the other hand, implies that the drink contains sugar.  However, it has been widely, and incorrectly, used oftentimes, to refer to sweetened drinks.

Comment: This explains some things but I'm afraid it doesn't answer to my question.

Comment: Do you have any source for the claim that  "sweet" implies that the drink contains sugar?  To me _sweet_  is primarily a description of taste, not implying any specific ingredient.

Comment: A substance tastes sweet because it has sugar

Comment: @QuIcKmAtHs Not exclusively. Aspartame, saccharine, stevia and other substances taste sweet but contain no sugar. Sweet is one of the [five basic tastes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5537773/) recognised by human beings and the sweet sensation is produced by the combination of stimulation of taste buds and processing of the resulting electrical impulse by the brain. Anything which produces a sweet sensation is sweet (though, arguably, only products sweetened with sugar can be described as 'sugary')

Answer (score 1):

I would challange both of your assumptions.

"sweetened" means that something has been added to the drink to make it taste sweeter (see Merriam-Webster definition ["1"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweetened)).  This something may be cane sugar, stevia, or something like aspartamine.  (You would need to check food and drink regulations in your jurisdiction to see if adding "grape juice" counts as "sweetened").

"sweet" means that the drink tastes sweet (see Merriam-Webster definition ["1(a)(2)"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweet)).  This may be because of naturally present sugars (for example: pure apple juice) or because the drink has been sweetened.  I would say that Diet Coke has a (sickly) sweet drink, but it has no sugar at all.

We have no one-word terms for "drinks without artificial sweetners".  We do have "unsweetened", which means nothing has been added.  Technically "drinks without artificial sweetners" includes "unsweetened", but in practise it means "sweetened with natural sweetners".

"Diet drinks" is as close as you will get for "drinks with artificial sweetners".

Comment: I think my problem is not "which one is the good formulation", but more "which formulation will be the best understood". Diet drink seems a good way to go, but since I'm targeting  scientific reporting, I'm afraid it could be seen as non-scientific.